# Layout of HTML element using dojo css

Tags: html, css, dojo

I'm working on a dojo 1.7 based project, where in one part of the project, I've to display HTML page in a browser like the format in following image:[image]

But I don't have any knowledge of CSS, and I don't know how to format the page like in above image. Is there any existing CSS file in dojo which can help me in providing the desirable format to the page?

Comment: Do you want to create the widgets programmatic or declarative?

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnfMd/) I made for you.

And result for this code in firefox (snapshot)
[image]

**Let me know if it solve your problem**

**Note: This is not exactly your solution, but you can modify it as per your need.**

Although you have to struggle something for your own, right? cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just want to know if there is any existing CSS file in dojo(I'm using claro as a theme for body tag), which automatically arranges all the HTML element in the format we desire, without us to do any CSS coding. I was asking this because I don't have any knowledge of CSS.